# jQuery $.post() request doesn't work unless ran twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

Here are two functions.

```
function getUserInformation(UserID) {
    $.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {
        UserID: UserID
    }, function (data) {
        if (data == "error") {
            alertBar('negative', 'There was an error sending the message');
        }
        window.username = data;
    })
}

function CreateChatBox(UserID) {
    if ($('#' + UserID).length == 0) {
        getUserInformation(UserID);
        alert(username);
    }
```

My issue is, that when the `CreateChatBox()` function is executed, it has to be clicked twice in order for it to actually work. How ever if I remove the `getUserInformation()` function from the `CreateChatBox()` function the `CreateChatBox()` function executes successfully.

Could anybody help me with this issue? Thanks.

---Edit (extra Detail)----

When I click a link `<a onclick = "CreateChatBox()">Some link</a>` nothing happens. But when I click it the second time it does work. If I remove the function `getUserInformation()` from the `CreateChatBox()` function the `CreateChatBox()` function works first time when the link is clicked.

Comment: how do you say it is actually working ? on what basis ?

Comment: What is the click mechanism that fires `CreateChatBox()`? Could you post that code?

Comment: `<a onclick = "CreateChatBox()">Some link</a>`

Comment: You need to run fiddler and watch the http traffic. That can usually show you the problem. If not, you can step into the .post method by hand and see what is happening. Also your response in this case might be getting cached. Set it to false to stop that. Use .ajax() instead and set the cache property to false. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Also do you have script debugging turned on? Maybe your throwing an error for some reason the first time and not seeing it?

Comment: @Frank what happens if you put one alert before "getUserInformation(UserID);"? Have you sure that getUserInformation is called twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the you are not waiting for ajax response to complete. When you click first time the ajax call is made through `post` and by second click the response is most likely available so you get it. You can see this putting alert inside the success handler.

```
function getUserInformation(UserID) {
   $.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", 
   {
         UserID: UserID
   }, 
   function(data){
         if (data == "error") {
             alertBar('negative','There was an error sending the message');
         }
         window.username = data;
         alert(window.username);
   });
}


function CreateChatBox(UserID) {
   if ($('#'+UserID).length==0) {
        getUserInformation(UserID);
   }
   //alert(username);
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah I imagine this is the problem. Second time through the response is cached.

Comment: As a side note, the first argument passed to the success handler is the jqXHR, the second one is the status message. So here `data` will never equal "error", you''l want to go with `function(data,msg){if(message==="error')`

Answer (score 1):

This is AJAX which means request is asynchronous. What you should do is to pass callback function as the second argument of your `getUserInformation` which will be invoked when data is available:

```
function getUserInformation(UserID, callback) {
    $.post("assets/scripts/chat/get_user_info.php", {UserID: UserID}, function(data) {
        if (data == "error") {
            alertBar('negative', 'There was an error sending the message');
        }
        callback(data);
    })
}


function CreateChatBox(UserID) {
    if ($('#'+UserID).length == 0) {
        getUserInformation(UserID, function(username) {
            alert(username);
        });
    }
}
```